# How do I change the Background Color of the middle of mat-expansion-panel (when expanded)?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      This is the expansion title
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      This is a summary of the content
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>

</mat-expansion-panel>
```

How do I change the `mat-panel-description` area (and **only** the `mat-panel-description` area so it is a different background color (e.g. red)?

I've tried various styles but cannot seem to get the entire background of that particular background to change (while keeping the header and footer their original colors).

Using chrome dev tools, adding a background-color to the following `.mat-expansion-panel-body` works, e.g.:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But this does not work when I try to put this in my stylesheet (or even via inline style).

**Note: This also works when I put this in my global stylesheet (styles.css) -- but I want to avoid doing this if possible.**

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRTqs.png) where I have a red circle indicating the area I want to change the background-color for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using global styles, but using a component-specific class as a parent (to prevent overriding all occurrences of `.mat-expansion-panel-body`)

I chose this method because I didn't want to use deprecated ng-deep or mess with my component's encapsulation.

**expansion-overview-example.component.html**

```
<div class="expansion-overview-example">
  <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
</div>
```

**styles.css**

```
.expansion-overview-example .mat-expansion-panel-body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in Angular use /deep/ to change styles for material component to force the style down with  Emulated encapsulation without changing the encapsulation, so try this:

```
/deep/ .mat-expansion-panel-body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

or ::ng-deep since /deep/ is deprecated

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add encapsulation property into your @Component decorator

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

and then you can simply add styles in your css file.

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
    background-color: red;
 }
```

Hope this helps!!